# What does the "-O-" in the middle of brands mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning

There are lots of brands or product names with an "O" joining two words with dashes. They seem to match the pattern ***verb*-o-*noun*** (or *verb-o-adj*), like:

- Break-o-day
- Clean-o-point
- Click-o-tron
- Cook-o-matic
- Drink-o-pop
- Drink-o-rama
- Dry-o-air
- Dry-o-lite
- Eat-o-keto
- Run-o-saur
- Walk-o-motion
- Wash-o-mat

What does this "O" mean? Can it be used with three (or more) words too?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible meanings of a prominent "O" in the middle of a brand name.

Most of the examples in the original post are following a pattern for combining Latin and Greek roots into words.  For example, "cryolite", "dinosaur", and "automatic".  The original post's examples look weird because at least one of the roots in the examples is not from Latin or Greek.

The other meaning is "of", as in "Break-o-day", "Drink-o-pop", and "Cup O' Noodles".

Comment: Why does it have to "mean" anything?